# How can I add a dll reference to a wpf project in visual studio?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using visual studio community 2019

The project settings : Application > Target framework : .Net Core 3.1
And : Build > Platform target: Any CPU

In winforms you click in the solution on the project name right click Add > Reference > Browse

But in wpf I can't find Add > Reference
This screenshot is of the wpf project.

[How to add dll reference to the project ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oySjl.jpg)

I tried right click on the solution name instead the project name and did Add > but again nothing there to add a reference.

[No add reference either right click on the solution name in the solution window on the right or either on the project name in the solution name on the right.  in both cases I make right click Add > but no add reference option.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipcMe.jpg)

Comment: Right  click on References in solution explore and then add

Comment: View>>Solutions Explorer.  References are listed there.

Comment: Ah right click and Add Project Reference this is the right one.  In winforms it's just Add Reference.